# Does auto increment start again at 0 if max value reached?

Tags: mysql, max, auto-increment, reset

Does MySQL's auto increment reset to `0` after reaching the maximum value?

In other words, if an `UNSIGNED SMALLINT` column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` reaches `65535` what happens on a new `INSERT`?

If there are no available values, what happens then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear on what happens:

> When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next
>   attempt to generate a sequence number fails.

Read about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

So the answer to your question is "no".  It generates an error.